# Case insensitive sorting via ORDER BY in google fusion table SELECT

Tags: sql, google-fusion-tables

Is it possible to make case insensitive sorting while selecting from fusion table using `ORDER BY column_name` clause?

In "general" SQL it could be done using `ORDER BY LOWER(field)` or `ORDER BY field COLLATE NOCASE`
but I didn't find a way how to do it using Google Fusion tables API.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not currently possible. Consider adding a feature request to our [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/).